# How do I check if a jquery function is exist to avoid duplicate func

Tags: jquery

I would like to check if a jquery function is exist. Example

```
var i = 0;

function callbuttonfunc(){
$("#button").click(function(){
   i += 1;
});
}
console.log(i);
```

if the we call callbuttonfunc() three times, when a we click the button, the increment value would be three times because of duplicate function. So I just want to implement a function which is not defined. Then, call a function to defined it. I could use $(document).ready() but I build an ajax website. So when a div is created. It would check every function which defined as undefined. Thank you

Comment: if (functionname == "undefined") ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to track if the event handler has been bound to the button already.

```
var i = 0;
var clickBound = false;

function callbuttonfunc(){
    if (clickBound) return;
    $("#button").on('click', function(){
       i += 1;
    });
    clickBound = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if that function is defined using below code:

```
function callbuttonfunc(){
$("#button").click(function(){
   i += 1;
});
}
if(isFunction(callbuttonfunc)) alert('is of type function');
if(isDefined(callbuttonfunc)) alert('if this is a function, it is defined');
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I mean to check $("#button").click(function(){}); not to check function callbuttonfunc()

Comment: You can check if button is triggered like : if (e.originalEvent !== undefined)
  {
    alert ('button clicked');
  }